# Is there Ehcache for php

Tags: php, caching

I am looking for caching solutions for php, so I was wondering if is there something like good and scalable as Ehcache, but for PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP official caching method is [memcached](http://www.memcached.org/) or check it on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or try [fastcache](http://www.phpfastcache.com/)